# Sum of specific elements of a list in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, count

> What question is asking for is a list that contains the number of all occurrences of the number 2 for a given index.

For example:

```
[1, 2, 2]
[2, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
```

Gives

```
[1,1,2]
```

While

```
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 1]
```

Gives:

```
[3,2,2]
```

Comment: Please clarify the question and use a readable example

Comment: I will try in some minutes, sorry about that

Comment: there are 4 2's in 4th element, how come it shows only 3 1's?

Comment: *After all that I should get a list like this:* What's this? Also I still don't understand your example...and what have you tried?

Comment: because u sum the 1st element with the 1st, 2nd with 2nd

Comment: yeah something like that

Comment: Oh man, can't able to understand the logic.

Comment: As it's presented at this moment, your question doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: So...maybe just sum all `1` in the list, replace `2` with `0`?

Comment: @KevinGuan it won't give the expected output. `[i.count(2) for i in l]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Ah...yeah, still can't understand...

Comment: this new exemple is completely understandable

Comment: @DavidNunes - are you interested in rotating `l` by 90 degrees to the right, and counting the number of twos in each row? Is that an accurate description of the problem?

Comment: Fine, now you give 3 example, which one is the correct one?

Comment: @KevinGuan - the first 2 example are the same, the expected output is the same, but for different matrixes. The 3rd example is another thing that I'd like to know, a similar thing but to count the 2s in each line of the given matrix

Comment: For your 3rd example, you can use `[i.count(2) for i in l]` as mentioned above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you're trying to rotate the matrix by 90 degrees to the right, then count the number of twos in each of the rows in the matrix:

```
from numpy import array

l = [[1, 2, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 1, 1, 1]]

result = [cur_l.count(2) for cur_l in array(l).T]
```

Output

```
print result
[2, 3, 2, 3, 3]
```

**Edit:**

Here's a solution without numpy:

```
>>> [cur_l.count(2) for cur_l in map(list, zip(*l))]
[2, 3, 2, 3, 3]
```

Comment: I think this answered my problem, but I dont understand what the cur_l is

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use `cur_l.count(2)` than `len([x for x in cur_l if x == 2])`

Comment: @DavidNunes - I can't read the code when it's squished into one line, but if you're interested in counting the twos in rows without transposing it, in the first solution, just remove the `.T` after `array(l)`; in the second solution, replace `map(list, zip(*l))`, with` l`. But that doesn't seem to be the question you were asking.

Comment: @Stuart - sure, that would work for the non-numpy solution. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: I wanted exactly what you showed me, I appreciate it

Comment: @DavidNunes - no problem!

Comment: @Boa - What if I want the same thing but for lines? Counting the number of 2s in each line?

Comment: @DavidNunes - I answered that in the above comment.

Comment: @Boa - Sorry, Iam kinda sleepy, thank you very much

Comment: @DavidNunes - no prob.

Comment: Numpy is total overkill, and it's more code. I don't like it...

Comment: @DavidNunes: Ah, if this answer helped you, remember accept it.

Comment: @PythonGuy - yes, that's why I gave two solutions without numpy.

Comment: Thank you all guys, I am sorry for all the mistakes, this was my first question. Just one more thing @Boa, can you link me something where I can read about the cur_l ? I get that it works but I didn't get why

Comment: @DavidNunes - `cur_l' is just a variable name: it has no special significance, and you can change it to almost anything else. The central concepts here are lists (or lists of lists, which are effectively, multi-dimensional arrays) and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: @Boa -  ok this was a stupid question, I am just not used to "for" cycles after using the variable even tho I know it can be used, I am not that bad...

Comment: @DavidNunes - don't worry about it, and there's no need to apologize while you're learning python. I highly recommend checking out the above link on list comprehensions - they're generally fast, and allow you to write clean, concise code.

Comment: @Boa - Hello again, would you check the question again? I found out that, after all, I didn't want the sum of all the occurrenses of 2s, I think the example is clear enough

Answer (score 2):

Iterate each index of your length five list, then look at all of those indices in l that contain a 2. If so, add 1 to a counter. Append that counter to a new list to after looking at each sub list in l.

```
l = [[1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    [2, 2, 1, 2, 2],
    [2, 2, 1, 1, 1]]

output = []
for i in range(0, len(l[0])):
    sum = 0
    for j in range(0, len (l)):
        if l[j][i] == 2:
            sum += 1
    output.append(sum)

print output
```

Outputs:

```
[2, 3, 2, 3, 3]
```

Comment: This works but avoid using `sum` as a variable name

Comment: @Stuart I'm new to programming, is this just a python convention, or is sum too general?

Comment: @MonteCarlo: Stuart means that `sum()` is a function name, use it as a variable name will not be able to use that function again.

Comment: Python will throw an error if you use a [keyword](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) as a variable name, but not if you use one of its [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) as a variable name, like `sum`. As Kevin says, using `sum` as a variable name should be avoided because you won't then be able to use the built-in function.

Comment: @Stuart - can you help me with my new problem? I actually want a thing a bit different from what I tought I wanted

Comment: @DavidNunes you mean for the rows? just use `[i.count(2) for i in l]`

Comment: @Stuart - I mean this new problem.. After all I didn't want the sum of all occurrences of 2s, I just want to sum the number of occurrences if they are consecutive. Just take a look at the problem above, I edited the question

Comment: @DavidNunes better to ask this as a new question than edit an existing one - it's confusing

Comment: @Stuart thing is I can't post questions for now.. :/ anyway thank you